# Term for someone who cannot keep something to themselves

Tags: word-request, word-usage

We have them everywhere. And I'm looking for the term to refer to them.

These are the people who cannot keep any matter to themselves. Irrespective of the degree of seriousness of the matter, they'll simply spit it out in front of others. In short, they are **not** eligible to say the idiom *I'll carry this to my grave!*

In my school/college days, we had a very informal term for them. We used to call such people *'the BBC'!* That's because if you have told anything to them, they'll spread the word for sure.

There could be more than one word. I'll be happy to have the closest term for it though.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blabbermouth?q=blabbermouth

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=big%20mouth&defid=2811648

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183214/what-do-you-call-someone-who-cant-keep-secrets

Comment: i normally use "town crier."  I could put this in proper format and put this as answer, but don't have too much time:(.  Anyone is free to put this as answer.:)

Comment: @Freddy isn't the term is used for some official who makes public announcement? It's quite formal I think.

Comment: Ah... big-mouth is too close (or probably the word!). @Freddy

Comment: Oh, I cannot comment there. The term OP is asking is ***'snitch'***. I'm pretty sure as he's looking for the  term *chugalkhor* in Hindi which means **snitch.** But yes, big-mouth is what I think fits.

Comment: I like the word loquacious, but the meaning it more someone that talks a lot, instead of someone that doesn't keep secrets.

Comment: what a word @stephenbayer. Loved it! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- [a big mouth](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+mouth) - if you have a big mouth, you talk too much, especially about things that should be secret
- [loose lip](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose_lip) - The practice or characteristic of being overly talkative, especially with respect to inadvertently revealing information which is private or confidential.

Answer (score 25):

Probably the word that closest fits your description is "blabbermouth". The dictionary definition of blabbermouth is "one who talks too much or indiscreetly" so it seems to be perfect for your needs.

Otherwise you could call them a gossip or an idiomatic expression would be that they "have a big mouth"

Comment: Yes, +1 for big-mouth. Blabbermouth won't fit exactly. I know the meaning of that word.

Comment: Based on that comment, your question is not posed clearly, for *blabbermouth* fits it exactly. Beyond that, *big mouth* does not mean only indiscreet, but *loose lip* does. IOW, *big mouth* matches the question as posed least, of these three answers.

Comment: @Drew show me the definition/source where you find blabbermouth fits my context.

Comment: @MaulikV: [Go for it](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+is+the+meaning+of+blabbermouth). It is someone who gossips indiscreetly, someone who cannot keep a secret,...

Comment: @Drew And what problem do you have with [this reference of Cambridge Idiom's Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+mouth) In addition, do you see the example there? 'Spreading news' is what exactly made us call someone the BBC in my olden days? It's mentioned in my question.

Comment: @MaulikV: I have no problem with it - choose any answer you like. To me, a *big mouth* is more general - applies in more contexts. To me it simply means someone who talks too much, not particularly who cannot keep a secret.

Answer (score 8):

Generally in a social and office environment the term "Gossip" can be used to describe the act and the person.

From The [OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gossip):

> A conversation about other people; an instance of gossiping: *she just comes round here for a gossip.* 
>   A person who likes talking about other people’s private lives*.

(*) It is marked as *chiefly derogatory* in the dictionaries.

Comment: +1. As I was not aware of *gossip* noun, I mean I can call someone *gossip*. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you're at the school age ( that doesn't seem so ;) ), I think the word "tattletale" would be the most proper word, However as an adult, I think the word that best fits your descriptions is "big-mouth" as mentioned in the other post.

Comment: Yes, I checked that word as well. As a synonym. It's a good word. 'Up' for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was once accused of being a "sieve" when I blabbed a secret, and when I've subsequently used it to describe others, everyone seemed to understand what I meant. Oxford Dictionaries doesn't seem to carry this definition but [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sieve) has

> a person who cannot keep a secret.

(The primary definition, of course, is that kitchen utensil with the mesh bottom for separating finer powders from coarser ones, like flour, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

As Peramia says, the informal term is "blabbermouth".

A more formal word would be to say that the person is "indiscreet".

If you ask someone to keep a secret and they don't, you can say they are "untrustworthy". But this word can also be used to describe someone who breaks promises or cheats or steals, so you may have to make clear what you mean in context.

If they talk about other people's personal lives they are a "gossip".

If a child tells about minor misdeeds of other children, he's a "tattletale". If someone tells the authorities about actual crimes committed by his friends or associates, he's a "stool pigeon" or a "stoolie". Those might not be quite what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Someone accused of possessing this trait, especially in relation to a specific, could be considered a ***grass*** or (colloquially, if not already) a ***grasser***.

Common to Scotland and UK, it is often preceded by a standard expletive and tends to refer to an event where someone ***squealed***.

To 'tell on someone' is to grass, though someone who is a blabbermouth (+1), or a gossip may not necessarily *be* a grass - but will likely to be known (and labelled as) a grasser.

The word renders someone definitely not eligible to carry the idiom *i'll carry this to my grave*.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not from the UK but I had heard the term grass in various TV programs, usually in the context of informing the police that someone was planning to do - or had done - something criminal. It looks like the term is also used in a wider context to simply mean "reveal a confidence".