# A term for someone who can keep a lot of secrets

Tags: word-request

There are [big mouth](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/term-for-someone-who-cannot-keep-something-to-themselves) people, and now I'm searching for the term that describes a person who can keep secret with them. Such people don't reveal what all they have in their minds. They are silent, *deep,* and master in hiding things within them.

I want a term for a neutral person. In other words, that person could be bad or good to you.

Note: [this person has nothing to do with country's secrets.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186257/what-do-you-call-someone-who-has-a-lot-of-power-and-keeps-a-big-secret)

Comment: "A reliable person", perhaps. "He is a good secret-keeper", maybe.

Comment: very general it is... @CowperKettle and obviously, I know that!

Comment: **Discreet** is a good word for this. If you can rely on someone's **discretion**, you know they will keep a secret or deal responsibly with sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are RETICENT, one not revealing one's thoughts or feelings readily.

- She is extremely reticent about her personal affairs.

Comment: Spot on! Exact sense, exact meaning, exact context!

Answer (score 5):

More idiomatic terms are [tight-lipped](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tight-lipped) and [closemouthed](https://www.wordnik.com/words/closemouthed). They could be considered antonyms to "big mouthed", and means the same thing as Barid's more formal answer, reticent.

Comment: Even closer to an antonym for “big mouthed” is “close mouthed” - they keep their mouth closed (note where the ‘ed’ is though!)

Comment: @JohnBurger Great suggestion!

Comment: If you look up the Simpsons character Johnny Tightlips, you'll find many great jokes on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that, at least to when it comes to keeping secrets, they are **trustworthy**:

> : worthy of confidence : DEPENDABLE
>   // a trustworthy guide
>   // trustworthy information

In other words, it's safe to entrust your secret to them.

Answer (score 0):

In Hindi, such a person is called "राजदार". In English, he is called a "confidant". To stress, you can say a "close confidant".

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of *adjectives* that might describe such a person... 'discreet' is one of the most commonly used ([far more common than 'reticent'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reticant%2C%20discreet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), for example).

But a *term* for such a person would have to be a noun, as your antonym of '[big-mouth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big-mouth)' is.

A *confidante* is someone you feel you can rely on to listen to and keep a secret.

Answer (score 0):

A "steel trap" is used colloquially in my region to refer to someone who will not readily reveal confidential information.

Comment: What region is that?

Comment: Midwestern united states. Animal trapping is common in my area and was a historical economic driver in my area specifically.